# Vertically-centered, 270° rotated text to the left of varying dynamic tables?

Tags: css, rotation, cross-browser, position, vertical-text

I'm dynamically generating several inline tables (varying in height) and I needs a **vertically centered, 270° rotated title to the left of each table**. I've tried several combinations of `transform`, `writing-mode`, positioning, etc.

I can get the text rotated in the right direction with a combination of `writing-mode: vertical-rl;`  and `transform:rotate(180deg);` but then positioning becomes a nightmare.

To further confuse matters, it's rendering differently in Firefox vs. Chrome and CodePen vs. SO snippet [below], basically giving me 3 variations. Prefixing (now commented out) didn't seem to make a difference.

I've been staring at this a long time; am I missing something obvious?!

---

## *What I want*:

[image: example of what I want]

---

## *What I have*:

<sup>*(The blue lines are container borders, included for comparison.)*</sup>
[image: examples of what I have]

```js
//ignore this; It just creates a bunch of duplicates
var els=document.body.getElementsByClassName('cont');
for(n=0;n<10;n++)els[1].insertAdjacentHTML('afterEnd', els[Math.round(Math.random())].cloneNode(1).outerHTML);
```

```css
body { font-family: arial; }

.cont {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 3px solid blue;
  margin: 2px 5px;
}

table {
  display: inline-block;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.title {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;

/* -ms-writing-mode: tb-rl; 
   -webkit-writing-mode: vertical-rl;
   -moz-writing-mode: vertical-rl;
   -ms-writing-mode: vertical-rl;  */

  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
/* transform:rotate(180deg); */
}
```

```html
<div class='cont'>
  <div class='title'>Title</div>
  <table>
    <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div class='cont'>
  <div class='title'>Title</div>
  <table>
    <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```